# how to get output for : if there is a skip in order id, then it is not recevied so next id should come in next row:

Tags: sql, oracle

if there is a skip in order id, then it is not recevied so next id should come in next row:

```
i/p table :
1000
1001
1002
1003
1005
1006
1007
1008
1010
1011
1014
1015
etc..

O/p:
1000-1003
1005-1008
1010-1011
1014-1015
```

How to get output from query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just to add the name frequently used for the strategy already mentioned: it's tabibitosan - http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2014/01/tabibitosan.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number()`, subtract it from your value, this way you get column which has same values for continuous data. Use this column for grouping, then find min and max:

**<sub>[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/1187)</sub>**

```
select min(id) ||' - '||max(id) op
  from (select id, id - row_number() over (order by id) grp from ip)
  group by grp order by grp
```

If your data contains duplicated values you have to get rid of them at first, use `distinct`.